# Google Cloud Storage Signed URLs -- How to specify a maximum file size?

Tags: http, upload, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, pre-signed-url

**Goal**

We would like users to be able to upload images to Google Cloud Storage.

**Problem**

We could achieve this indirectly with our server as a middle man -- first, the user uploads to our server, then our privileged server can upload to Cloud Storage.

However, we think this is unnecessarily slow, and instead would like the user to upload directly to Cloud Storage.

**Proposed Solution**

To achieve a direct upload, we generate a [Signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) on our server. The Signed URL specifies an expiration time, and can only be used with the HTTP PUT verb. A user can request a Signed URL, and then - for a limited time only - upload an image to the path specified by the Signed URL.

**Problem with the Solution**

*Is there any way to enforce a maximum file upload size?* Obviously we would like to avoid users attempting to upload 20GB files when we expect <1MB files.

It seems like this is an obvious vulnerability, yet I don't know how to address it while still using SignedURLs.

There seems to be a way to do this using Policy Documents ([Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395592/google-cloud-storage-how-to-limit-size-of-user-uploads)), but the question is over 2 years old now.

Answer (score 9):

For all looking at the answer today be aware that [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/parameters#xgoogcontentlengthrange)

```
x-goog-content-length-range:0,25000
```

is the way to limit the upload size between 0 and 25000 bytes Cloud Storage.

`X-Upload-Content-Length` will not work and you are still able to upload larger files

Comment: I tested `x-goog-content-length-range` this and what it does is to truncate the uploaded file and does not  cancel on wrong size.

Comment: i tried this, but x-goog-content-length-range is not working, where does it go in?  `$url = $object->signedUrl(new \DateTime('120 min'),['method' => 'PUT','contentType' => "$type",'version' => 'v4', 'x-goog-content-length-range' => '0,1' ]);`

Comment: x-goog-content-length-range: min-bytes,max-bytes works perfect when signing with the python library. when the upload attempt is missing the matching header, it fails with a missing header error. when the size of the upload is too large, it fails with a wrong-size error. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

Signing **content-length** should do the trick.

Google Cloud will not allow uploads with larger file size even if the **content-length** is set to a lower value.

This is how the signed url options should look like:

```
const writeOptions: GetSignedUrlConfig = {
  version: 'v4',
  action: 'write',
  expires: Date.now() + 900000, // 15 minutes
  extensionHeaders: {
    "content-length": length // desired length in bytes
  }
}
```

Comment: this worked nicely for me. It works for PUT requests too

Answer (score 5):

Policy documents are still the right answer. They are documented here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#policydocument

The important part of the policy document you'll need is:

```
["content-length-range", <min_range>, <max_range>].
```

Comment: The same link says this: "_Note: Unless you need to use HTML forms (usually through a web browser) to upload objects, we strongly recommend using PUT object instead of POST._". However, there is no `content-length-range` defined for PUT objects. Is this a feature that is included, but not documented?

Comment: No, it only exists for POST, unfortunately.

Comment: So Google recommends using PUT for uploading objects to Cloud Storage, but doesn't allow you to specify a maximum file size??? Seems like PUT is totally useless then...

Comment: With `PUT` method, you can try using `x-goog-content-length-range` header. More info available on https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#xgoogcontentlengthrange

Comment: i tried this, but x-goog-content-length-range is not working, where does it go in? `$url = $object->signedUrl(new \DateTime('120 min'),['method' => 'PUT','contentType' => "$type",'version' => 'v4', 'x-goog-content-length-range' => '0,1' ]);`

Answer (score 1):

My worked code in NodeJS was following https://blog.koliseo.com/limit-the-size-of-uploaded-files-with-signed-urls-on-google-cloud-storage/. You must use the version `v4`

```
 public async getPreSignedUrlForUpload(
    fileName: string,
    contentType: string,
    size: number,
    bucketName: string = this.configService.get('DEFAULT_BUCKET_NAME'),
  ): Promise<string> {
    const bucket = this.storage.bucket(bucketName);
    const file = bucket.file(fileName);

    const response = await file.getSignedUrl({
      action: 'write',
      contentType,
      extensionHeaders: {
        'X-Upload-Content-Length': size,
      },
      expires: Date.now() + 60 * 1000, // 1 minute
      version: 'v4',
    });

    const signedUrl = this.maskSignedUrl(response[0], bucketName);
    return signedUrl;
  }
```

In the Frontend, We must set the same number of the Size in the header `X-Upload-Content-Length`

```
export async function uploadFileToGCP(
  signedUrl: string,
  file: any
): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
        resolve(this.responseText);
      }
    });

    xhr.open('PUT', signedUrl, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', file.type);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Upload-Content-Length', file.size);

    xhr.send(file);
  });
}
```

And also don't forget to config the `responseHeader` in the `GS CORS`

```
gsutil cors get gs://asia-item-images
[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["GET", "OPTIONS", "PUT"], "origin": ["*"], "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "X-Upload-Content-Length", "X-Goog-Resumable"]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `X-Upload-Content-Length` instead of `Content-Length`. [See blog post here](https://blog.koliseo.com/limit-the-size-of-uploaded-files-with-signed-urls-on-google-cloud-storage/).

On the server side (Java):

```
Map<String, String> extensionHeaders = new HashMap<>();
extensionHeaders.put("X-Upload-Content-Length", "" + contentLength);
extensionHeaders.put("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

var url =
  storage.signUrl(
    blobInfo,
    15,
    TimeUnit.MINUTES,
    Storage.SignUrlOption.httpMethod(HttpMethod.PUT),
    Storage.SignUrlOption.withExtHeaders(extensionHeaders),
    Storage.SignUrlOption.withV4Signature()
  );
```

On the client side (typescript):

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'X-Upload-Content-Length': `${file.size}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
  },
  body: file,
});
```

You will need to set up a cors policy on your bucket:

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["https://your-website.com"],
    "responseHeader": [
      "Content-Type",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "X-Upload-Content-Length",
      "x-goog-resumable"
    ],
    "method": ["PUT", "OPTIONS"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

Comment: This also worked for me. More detail at this link: https://blog.koliseo.com/limit-the-size-of-uploaded-files-with-signed-urls-on-google-cloud-storage/

Comment: This allows for uploads that go above the desired limit, you only need to lie about X-Upload-Content-Length when signing and set the same value when doing the actual upload.

Comment: @RaduDiță The signing is done on the server side, not the client side. The idea is to validate content length before signing, and throw an exception if it's not valid.

Comment: @NachoColoma Even if the checking is done on the server side, you can lie on the client side when upload. GCS doesn't check if the provided X-Upload-Content-Length is the actual content length. You can get a valid signature for 1MB for instance and upload a 2MB document. The only way I was able to get GCS to actually block the upload is to use Content-Length.

Comment: exactly what Radu said. Client asks server for a signedUrl for a file size of 10kb. Server responds with a URL saying: you may upload your file but it needs to contain this header: "X-Upload-Content-Length: 10kb". Client uploads 100mb file with header: "X-Upload-Content-Length: 10kb".