# Upload large files on Google Storage with PHP 7 library

Tags: google-cloud-platform, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I need to upload larger file on google stoarge.

Actually, what I'm doing is to create an URL in this way:

```
$url = $object->beginSignedUploadSession([
    "options" => [
        "x-goog-x-upload-content-type" => "$type",
        "x-goog-content-type" => "$type",
    ]
]);
```

On frontend, I'm fetching this URL and make a PUT request with file

```
let type = files[i].type;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/getUrl",
    data: dataToPass,
    success: function (json) {
        var jsonParse = JSON.parse(json);
        var url = jsonParse.url;
        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('file', files[i]);

        var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
            type:'PUT',
            url: url,
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: type,
            cache: false,
                xhr: function () {
                    myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    if (    myXhr.upload) {
                        myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', thisIsAFunction, false);
                    }
                    return  myXhr;
                },
```

Upload seems works, but on my storage file is corrupted.
[image]

Actually the filetype is mp4, but storage save it as applicastion/octet-stream. Filesize is correct but file not working.

This is the PUT request payload
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved by passing directly the file to Ajax, without appending it to the form data.

```
var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                type:'PUT',
                url: url,
                data: files[i],
                processData: false,
                contentType: type,
                cache: false, ....code goes on...
```

Correct way to pass contentType for the bucket is:

```
$url = $object->beginSignedUploadSession([
        "contentType" => $type,
        ...... 
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there is no `contentType` defined for the file during the upload.

This shouldn't be happening since you have a extension for the file in the filename so this lead me to believe that even though you are providing a `contentType`, it has an invalid value and saves it as a file without extension.

So in order to fix it I would advise you to log and check the value of your `type` variable, as this is likely the cause of the issue. The proper value that it need to have in order to upload the file as a `.mp4` video is `video/mp4`.

Comment: Solved as wrote. Just to be curious, there is a way to specify content-length-range and a success_action_redirect while generating beginSignedUploadSession?

Comment: Not with a `content-length-range`, but you can use a specific `content-length` for setting a top limit, as described in this [community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66841197/12857703), as per the `success_action_redirect` I could not find anything in the documentation nor community posts so can't say for sure.

Comment: Adding content-length does not block user to upload larger file :/ maybe some syntax is wrong? https://pastebin.com/MDLbSkSV

Comment: Tried removing "options" from array and just use "headers" with valuse, still nothing

Comment: I think this might be worth asking in a separate question then :)