# Setting File Size Limits with Signed URLs in Google Cloud Storage v4

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage using a signed URL and I want to restrict the file size during upload. Previously, with signed URL version 2, I could set the `conditions` parameter to enforce size restrictions, but when attempting to do the same using version 4, I receive an error stating that `conditions` is no longer a valid argument.

Here's the error message I encountered:

```
TypeError: Blob.generate_signed_url() got an unexpected keyword argument 'conditions'
```

Below is a sample of my code that results in this error:

```py
# Sample code for generating a signed URL with size limitation
from google.cloud import storage
from django.conf import settings
from datetime import timedelta

class GcsHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bucket_name = settings.GS_BUCKET_NAME
        self.storage_client = storage.Client()
        self.bucket = self.storage_client.bucket(self.bucket_name)

    def generate_signed_url(self, blob_name: str, content_type: str, file_size: int) -> str:
        """
        Generate a signed URL for a blob to upload a file with a specific size limit.

        :param blob_name: The path to the GCS file.
        :param content_type: The content type of the file.
        :param file_size: The exact file size limit for the upload.
        :return: The signed URL.
        """
        blob = self.bucket.blob(blob_name)
        url = blob.generate_signed_url(
            version="v4",
            expiration=timedelta(minutes=60),
            method="PUT",
            content_type=content_type,
            conditions=[
                ["content-length-range", file_size, file_size]
            ]
        )
        return url
```

After reviewing the implementation of `generate_signed_url` in [`google/cloud/storage/bucket.py`](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/blob/main/google/cloud/storage/bucket.py), I confirmed that the `conditions` parameter is indeed missing:

```py
# google/cloud/storage/bucket.py function definition for reference
def generate_signed_url(
    self,
        expiration=None,
        api_access_endpoint=_API_ACCESS_ENDPOINT,
        method="GET",
        headers=None,
        query_parameters=None,
        client=None,
        credentials=None,
        version=None,
        virtual_hosted_style=False,
        bucket_bound_hostname=None,
        scheme="http",
    ):
```

I am looking for a way to limit file size using `generate_signed_url` version 4. If anyone knows a workaround or the correct method to impose such a limit, please advise.

Comment: can you check the examples in this  [article1](https://www.appsloveworld.com/google-cloud-platform/2/google-cloud-storage-signed-urls-how-to-specify-a-maximum-file-size?expand_article=1) & [article2](https://blog.koliseo.com/limit-the-size-of-uploaded-files-with-signed-urls-on-google-cloud-storage/)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I solved this problem!

Answer (score 0):

**Aiswarya Sathi** kindly introduced the following two articles in the comments, which have been very useful for specifying the file size for uploads using Google Cloud Storage's signed URLs:

- [Google Cloud Storage Signed URLs: How to Specify a Maximum File Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812595/google-cloud-storage-signed-urls-how-to-specify-a-maximum-file-size)
- [Limit the size of uploaded files with signed URLs on Google Cloud Storage](https://blog.koliseo.com/limit-the-size-of-uploaded-files-with-signed-urls-on-google-cloud-storage/)

Based on this information, I'm sharing my implementation in a Python environment. The three main points to note are as follows:

1. Change the CORS settings to ensure that `"Content-Type"` and `"X-Upload-Content-Length"` are authorized in requests from the client to the server.
2. Include these header details when creating the signed URL.
3. When actually using the signed URL to upload a file, set the file size and content type in the header.

An example of the CORS settings is shown in the following JSON file:

```json
[
  {
    "origin": ["http://0.0.0.0:8089"],
    "responseHeader": [
      "Content-Type",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "X-Upload-Content-Length",
      "x-goog-resumable"
    ],
    "method": ["GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

Here is how to generate a signed URL in Python:

```py
def generate_upload_signed_url(self, blob_name, content_type, file_size):
    """Generates a v4 signed URL for uploading a blob using HTTP PUT."""
    blob = self.bucket.blob(blob_name)
    headers = {
        "X-Upload-Content-Length": str(file_size),
        "Content-Type": content_type
    }
    logger.info(f"headers: {headers}")

    url = blob.generate_signed_url(
        version="v4",
        expiration=timedelta(minutes=60),
        method="PUT",
        headers=headers
    )
    return url
```

And the method to upload a file using JavaScript is as follows:

```js
async function uploadFileToSignedUrl(file, signedUrl) {
    console.log(`file size: ${file.size} file type: ${file.type} uploading ${file.name} to ${signedUrl}`);
    const res = await fetch(signedUrl, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': file.type,
            'X-Upload-Content-Length': file.size.toString(),
        },
        body: file,
    });
    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error('Upload failed');
    }
    return res.ok;
}
```

By following these steps, you can securely upload files to Google Cloud Storage. I hope this answer will be of help to someone.